# Why is King Kai still dead?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

Near the end of the Cell Saga, Cell inflates its body in preparation to destroy the earth, but Goku thwarted its plans by teleporting it to King Kai's planet. As a result, King Kai and Goku were both killed by Cell's explosion. After Cell was finally defeated, however, they used the Dragon Balls to revive everyone killed by Cell. Goku wouldn't be revived since he was already brought back once, but shouldn't King Kai, Gregory, and Bubbles have been revived? Cell was the direct cause of their deaths.

Comment: because who was it that *moved* the bomb called Cell to King Kai's Planet?

Comment: @Memor-X So what you're saying is that Goku is more responsible for King Kai's death because Cell had no intent to kill King Kai, but Goku was fully aware what would happen if he teleported Cell to King Kai's planet. Therefore, Shenron considers it to be Goku who killed King Kai. Would you like to write an answer about that?

Comment: i would but i don't have the confidence i can form a good enough answer unless i re-watch the episode to confirm some stuff. watching Team Four Star's Abridge version New Shenron would have had 3 wishes like Porunga but it was nerfed to 2 to remove the "only 1 resurrection" catch which Shenron had and i know Goku said to the others that he didn't want to bring him back citing all the previous threats to earth came because of him. just need to check the first wish to confirm what another factors could've stopped Goku being resurrected in the first wish

Answer (score 6):

The exact wish (at least in the english dub) was

> Please revive all those on Earth who were killed by Cell.

That doesn't include the others who died on King Kai's planet.

Comment: The wording in the English dub of Kai spoken by Yamcha was "For our first wish, we want you to bring back everyone who was killed by Cell." I'm assuming your wording comes from the original series. In this case, further investigation into the Japanese versions and the manga would improve this answer.

Comment: Also in Kai, Piccolo expresses disappointment afterwards that Goku wasn't revived (evidently he was holding onto a faint hope that the new Shenron would be able to revive him). According to the wording of the wish you've given, Piccolo would have no reason to believe Goku would be revived since he was neither killed by Cell on earth, nor is he currently on earth. Of course, it's possible Piccolo wasn't aware Yamcha made the "wrong wish".

Answer (score 3):

When Goku was talking to them he explained that King Kai could have been brought back to life by the wish but refused so he could stay with Goku and guide him around, but why he needed to be dead for this was never explained. Two fan theories I've read to explain this is that he couldn't enter heaven unless dead and that by being dead he could ignore his duties as North Kai, neither of these make sense to me though as we see a lively South Kai in heaven in the manga and we cannot say what is actually required of him in regards to his Kai duties of which we assumingly see him having resumed back on his planet in Super whilst still dead.

So to get back to your question he chose not to be revived at the time and Goku never attempted to revive him since, due to forgetting and not seeing it as a big deal since he's a god, until King Kai expressed his desire for it.

Comment: I've also seen this in forums, but it wasn't sourced. Do you know what volume or manga chapter that was in? The anime episode would also be acceptable (though I'd prefer the manga). The exact quote of what King Kai said would also be good.